# Possible to get firewire on a new laptop that only has usb3 and thunderbolt?

Tags: sound-card, usb-3, firewire, asus-laptop, pro-tools

I was wondering if it's possible to somehow get Firewire on my Asus rog g751jy? It's fairly new and really powerful computer, but doesn't have a built-in firewire port. It does however have USB3.0

I'm aware that usb and firewire aren't really interchangeable, but I was reading that some external Lacie usb3 drives have firewire interfaces on them. Could that be used to connect a firewire PreSonus sound card to this laptop? I was thinking on using this laptop to work with ProTools 10HD

Edit: This laptop supposedly have Thunderbolt available through the Display Port. Could that be a way?